# Passing parameters to KnockOut Js text binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, parameters

How can I pass a custom parameter to a text binding?

My HTML

```
<span data-bind="text: something"></span>
```

I really want something like this

```
<span data-bind="text: something('123456')"></span>
```

So that the `span` ends up containing the text 'Something was sent 123456'

```
self.something = ko.computed(function(p)
{
    return "Something was sent " + p;
}, this);
```

The overarching problem is that I have several of those spans, each has a different count from an observable array. I had used this but it seems very cumbersome having all those very similar count functions in my ViewModel.

```
<span data-bind="text: countFemale"></span>
<span data-bind="text: countMale"></span>
<span data-bind="text: countFrogs"></span>
<span data-bind="text: countCars"></span>
```

**EDIT**

My count function looks like this

```
self.areaCount = ko.computed(function(areaName)
{
  console.log(this);
  var c = 0; 
  $.each(self.progression(), function(i, obj){                       
    if(obj.model.area() == areaName)
      c++;            
  });

  if(c == 0)
    return '';

  return "(" + c + ")";

}, this);
```

Note that I want to be able to pass in an `areaName` to avoid having lots of functions like this

```
self.areaCount = ko.computed(function()
{
  console.log(this);
  var c = 0; 
  $.each(self.progression(), function(i, obj){                       
    if(obj.model.area() == "male")
      c++;            
  });

  if(c == 0)
    return '';

  return "(" + c + ")";

}, this);

self.areaCount = ko.computed(function()
{
  console.log(this);
  var c = 0; 
  $.each(self.progression(), function(i, obj){                       
    if(obj.model.area() == "female")
      c++;            
  });

  if(c == 0)
    return '';

  return "(" + c + ")";

}, this);

self.areaCount = ko.computed(function()
{
  console.log(this);
  var c = 0; 
  $.each(self.progression(), function(i, obj){                       
    if(obj.model.area() == "frogs")
      c++;            
  });

  if(c == 0)
    return '';

  return "(" + c + ")";

}, this);

self.areaCount = ko.computed(function()
{
  console.log(this);
  var c = 0; 
  $.each(self.progression(), function(i, obj){                       
    if(obj.model.area() == "cars")
      c++;            
  });

  if(c == 0)
    return '';

  return "(" + c + ")";

}, this);
```

Comment: can you explain more your goal?

Comment: Those spans all contain a number, that number is a count of specific elements within an observable array. It seems silly have so many functions that are so similar, I want to be able to have just one function and pass in a parameter which determines what type of count should be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried just using a function:

```
<div data-bind="text: showCount('frogs')"></div>
```

Then on your view model add this property:

```
showCount: function (value) { return '(' + value + ')'; }
```

In your case, pass through the area name to the test function and do your filtering.

Comment: I had tried that, but must have done something wrong as I have just retried it and its worked.

Comment: Ah, the old classic! Been there, done that, glad to help sort it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to use a simple function - I was messing about with computed.